# ORA-01722 INVALID NUMBER-Unsure of Solution

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been handed this roughly put together a script where we attain more information from other tables based on a long numerical ran number. In past it has worked absolutely fine until recently when we have received an error message "ORA-01722- Invalid Number"

I have whittled down the ran numbers that are causing this and they are as follows.
,'85130081073110917595533'
,'85130081074110038783421'
,'85130081081111498340562'

They are no different from other RaN numbers that seem to work such as; '85130060209029787144704'

The only difference I can identify is that the ones that are pulling the error message all have the same user id within one of the tables, that being user_ID '00000004108005' which is 14 characters, every other merchant_id fluctuates between 8/12. So im wondering if its got something to do with regexp not factoring in the additional zeros?
To be honest i really don't know and I have done quite a lot of reading into it, I know its directly linked with oracle thinking its dealing with numeric but encounters something else.

Please find below the syntax and if you have anything to advise to potentially remove this error message it would be massively appreciated if not, at least I posted my second question to you awesome guys :D

Hope ya'll have  a lovely day, holla if you need anything clarified as im still quite new to the world of stackoverflow/sql

```
`
`WITH TABLE1 as --psuedo table using with clause
                          (
                            SELECT pr.id as seq_nbr,
                            regexp_substr(pr.merchant_reference_code, '[^- ]+',1,1)  as MG_ID,
                            regexp_substr(pr.merchant_reference_code, '[^- ]+',1,2)  as ENTRY_POINT,
                            TABLE2.ID TR_ID,  -- from psuedo table subquery TABLE2
                            TABLE2.op_friendly_order_id, -- from psuedo table subquery TABLE2
                            TABLE2.START_DATE_TIME,  -- from psuedo table subquery TABLE2
                            TABLE2.CU_ID
                            FROM table1 --real table
                            JOIN (-- items in subquery must be reference in above to be usable, and use the subquery alias. in this case TABLE2
                                            SELECT
                                            T.ID,
                                            T.op_friendly_order_id,
                                            NVL2(t.op_friendly_order_id,
                                            T.op_friendly_order_id, T.ID) REF_ID,
                                            T.START_DATE_TIME,
                                            G.CU_ID
                                            FROM table2 T ,
                                           table3 G --real table
                                            WHERE t.cmd_date_created > '01-MAR-2017'
                                            AND T.ID = G.TR_ID
                                 ) TABLE2 --psuedo table using sub-query and joined to real table 
                                                                            on TABLE2.REF_ID = regexp_substr(merchant_reference_code, '[^- ]+',1,3)
                          WHERE request_date >= '01-MAR-2017'
                            )
SELECT --TABLE1.*
--TABLE1.SEQ_NBR,
OT.RRN,
TABLE1.MG_ID,
TABLE1.ENTRY_POINT,
TR_ID,
TABLE1.OP_FRIENDLY_ORDER_ID,
TABLE1.START_DATE_TIME BOOKING_DATE_TIME,
TABLE1.CU_ID
FROM table 4 ot --real table
JOIN TABLE1
      ON table1.seq_nbr = ot.rrn
WHERE ot.btch_date >= '01-MAR-2017'
AND ot.ran IN (
'')
```

Comment: The only regexes are against merchant_reference_code, and you don't refer to user_id in the code. We can't see the table structures or data, so we can't tell where you might be doing implicit conversions that could cause the error. (You are doing implicit date conversions, which is a bad idea.) The `TABLE2.REF_ID = regexp_substr...` looks suspicious though. Try to run the CTE query standalone for a specific RAN, and take bits out until it works; or look at relevant values from the real tables. You need to do some basic debugging, in other words.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex that's super duper helpful, i'm going to delayer it and see what's going on. Thank's again for the advice though its really appreciated

Comment: Right, so look at the `on` condition; if `ref_id` is a number then query just whichever part has `merchant_reference_code`, and see what the regex produces - maybe that is usually digits but sometimes isn't. Or look at the data types for the columns used in the `nvl2()` call.

Comment: @AlexPoole       Hi Alex so I went back and just ran with the CTE and was getting the same error message. I am only selecting the RAN from t1

The inner join im doing is  'From Table1 INNER JOIN Table 2 ON
t1.id =t2.rrn

This is without any implicit date conversions and only filtering with the RAN numbers.
When I looked at the data types of both t1.id & t2.rrn - t1 is data type number and t2 is data type VARCHAR. Would that have anything to do with that error message?

Comment: Yes, because it has to do an implicit conversion. So, look for rrn values that don't look like numbers.

Comment: @AlexPoole Hi there alex, thank you so much for your patience and tolerance over something that now seems very obvious. I clearly am showing my newness to this all but I find it really really interesting. So you are absolutely correct the ones proving to be difficult have an RRN of CA-84755845 whilst the ones pulling through are just 841465619, 841857244. So that's why oracle isn't having it with the others ones!